# Spacy to extract specific noun phrase

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

Can I use spacy in python to find NP with specific neighbors? I want Noun phrases from my text that has verb before and after it.

Comment: Text and output example ?

Answer (score 13):

1. You can merge the noun phrases ( so that they do not get tokenized seperately).
2. Analyse the dependency parse tree, and see the POS of neighbouring tokens.

   ```
   >>> import spacy
   >>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
   >>> sent = u'run python program run, to make this work'
   >>> parsed = nlp(sent)
   >>> list(parsed.noun_chunks)
   [python program]
   >>> for noun_phrase in list(parsed.noun_chunks):
   ...     noun_phrase.merge(noun_phrase.root.tag_, noun_phrase.root.lemma_, noun_phrase.root.ent_type_)
   ... 
   python program
   >>> [(token.text,token.pos_) for token in parsed]
   [(u'run', u'VERB'), (u'python program', u'NOUN'), (u'run', u'VERB'), (u',', u'PUNCT'), (u'to', u'PART'), (u'make', u'VERB'), (u'this', u'DET'), (u'work', u'NOUN')]
   ```
3. By analysing the POS of adjacent tokens, you can get your desired noun phrases.
4. A better approach would be to analyse the [dependency parse tree](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/dependency-parse#navigating), and see the lefts and rights of the noun phrase, so that even if there is a punctuation or other POS tag between the noun phrase and verb, you can increase your search coverage

Comment: It looks good but I want to automatically fetch all the Noun Phrase that has Verbs before and after it. For one sentence, one can easily read, analyze and parse but what about a panda data frame with 5000 records and each record has one cell of text that you want to analyze.

Comment: That should be trivial too.

Comment: Actually, I am doing spacy for the first time and very new to NLP. In your answer you are outputting all the tokens and the pos tags attached with them. I am interested in extracting NourPhrases that has verbs before after it.

Comment: `(u'run', u'VERB'), (u'python program', u'NOUN'), (u'run', u'VERB')` what does this line signify about "python program"  ?

Comment: isn't it all tokenized words with their POS tags. In this case, it happened to be in the order of Verb+noun+Verb. I was looking to extract all such combination from a large corpus of text. I did some reading and I think, it can be easily done by navigating the parse tree.

Comment: I think, that you basically got the answer to your question handed to you on a plate, and almost sounds like you fail to see it. As @DhruvPathak indicates, either you phrased your question badly and you actually mean something else, but otherwise this code looks like it does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: One key part was extracting only verb noun verb patterns, so no, he did not get the answer handed on a plate.  And I am also having a similar question and do not see the answer here.

Comment: @HuckIt The answer does lie on the plate if observed with a keen eye. You would indeed see the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

From https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#dependency-parse

You can use `Noun chunks`.
Noun chunks are "base noun phrases" – flat phrases that have a noun as their head. You can think of noun chunks as a noun plus the words describing the noun – for example, "the lavish green grass" or "the world’s largest tech fund". To get the noun chunks in a document, simply iterate over `Doc.noun_chunks`.

```
In:
        import spacy
    ​    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
        doc = nlp(u"Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers")
        for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
            print(chunk.text)

Out:

        Autonomous cars
        insurance liability
        manufacturers
```

Comment: This doesn't filter noun chunks to only chunks that have verbs before and after it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-tokenize using merge phrases, I prefer this (rather than noun chunks) :

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('merge_noun_chunks'))
doc = nlp(u"Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text)
```

and the output will be :

```
Autonomous cars
shift
insurance liability
toward
manufacturers
```

I choose this way because each token has property for further process :)